# Remove duplication in SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

SQL Practice from W3Schools

```sql
SELECT C.country, 
       Round(Sum(P.price * OD.quantity), 2) AS Revenue 
FROM   [orders] AS O 
       INNER JOIN [orderdetails] AS OD 
               ON O.orderid = OD.orderid 
       INNER JOIN [products] AS P 
               ON OD.productid = P.productid 
       INNER JOIN [customers] AS C 
               ON O.customerid = C.customerid 
WHERE  C.country = (SELECT C.country 
                    FROM   [orders] AS O 
                           INNER JOIN [orderdetails] AS OD 
                                   ON O.orderid = OD.orderid 
                           INNER JOIN [products] AS P 
                                   ON OD.productid = P.productid 
                           INNER JOIN [customers] AS C 
                                   ON O.customerid = C.customerid 
                    GROUP  BY C.customerid 
                    ORDER  BY Round(Sum(P.price * OD.quantity), 2) DESC 
                    LIMIT  1)
```

My joins are duplicated from main to sub-query.
Is there anyway to reduce code replication in this query?

Comment: Can you please add details what is the problem you are facing and what are you trying to achieve with the query ? Please read the [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I suspect the key here is a [CTE](https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/using-common-table-expressions/).

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp
is this what you are looking for?